# Multiple variable distribution plot using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have different categorical variable which I would like to show in terms of distribution.

[image: the plot im trying to recreate]

So in my data-frame I have like 147 patients and their traits such as age,gender,disease subtypes etc etc.

This is my dataframe subset

```
head(plot_meta)
       patient    Sex FAB Diagnosis-Age Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage                                                          Cytogenetics
1 TCGA-AB-2856   Male  M4            63                           82                                                             46,XY[20]
2 TCGA-AB-2849   Male  M0            39                           83 47,XY,del(5)(q22q33),t(10;11)(p13~p15;q22~23),i(17)(q10)[3]/46,XY[17]
3 TCGA-AB-2971 Female  M4            76                           91                                                             46,XX[20]
4 TCGA-AB-2930 Female  M2            62                           72                                                            46, XX[20]
5 TCGA-AB-2891   Male  M1            42                           68           45,XY,der(7)(t:7;12)(p11.1;p11.2),-12,-13,+mar[19]/46,XY[1]
6 TCGA-AB-2872   Male  M3            42                           88         46,XY,del(9)(q13:q22),t(11:21)(p13;q22),t(15;17)(q22;q210[20]
  Cytogenetic-Code--Other-     Induction
1         Normal Karyotype 7+3+Genasense
2     Complex Cytogenetics         7+3+3
3         Normal Karyotype           7+3
4         Normal Karyotype       7+3+AMD
5     Complex Cytogenetics         7+3+3
6                 PML-RARA      7+3+ATRA
```

So my goal is to show the patient traits distribution as the above figure.

```
a <- dput(head(plot_meta))
structure(list(patient = structure(c(36L, 33L, 122L, 95L, 66L, 
49L), .Label = c("TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2808", 
"TCGA-AB-2810", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2812", "TCGA-AB-2813", 
"TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2817", "TCGA-AB-2818", 
"TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2820", "TCGA-AB-2821", "TCGA-AB-2822", 
"TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2825", "TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2828", 
"TCGA-AB-2830", "TCGA-AB-2834", "TCGA-AB-2835", "TCGA-AB-2836", 
"TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2840", "TCGA-AB-2841", "TCGA-AB-2842", 
"TCGA-AB-2843", "TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2845", "TCGA-AB-2846", 
"TCGA-AB-2847", "TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-2853", 
"TCGA-AB-2856", "TCGA-AB-2857", "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2859", 
"TCGA-AB-2861", "TCGA-AB-2862", "TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-2865", 
"TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2867", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2870", 
"TCGA-AB-2871", "TCGA-AB-2872", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2874", 
"TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2876", "TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-2878", 
"TCGA-AB-2880", "TCGA-AB-2881", "TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2883", 
"TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2885", "TCGA-AB-2886", "TCGA-AB-2888", 
"TCGA-AB-2889", "TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2892", 
"TCGA-AB-2893", "TCGA-AB-2894", "TCGA-AB-2895", "TCGA-AB-2896", 
"TCGA-AB-2897", "TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-2900", 
"TCGA-AB-2901", "TCGA-AB-2908", "TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2911", 
"TCGA-AB-2912", "TCGA-AB-2913", "TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2915", 
"TCGA-AB-2916", "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2919", 
"TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2925", 
"TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2928", "TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2930", 
"TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2932", "TCGA-AB-2933", "TCGA-AB-2934", 
"TCGA-AB-2935", "TCGA-AB-2936", "TCGA-AB-2937", "TCGA-AB-2938", 
"TCGA-AB-2939", "TCGA-AB-2940", "TCGA-AB-2941", "TCGA-AB-2942", 
"TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2944", "TCGA-AB-2946", "TCGA-AB-2948", 
"TCGA-AB-2949", "TCGA-AB-2950", "TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2955", 
"TCGA-AB-2956", "TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2965", 
"TCGA-AB-2966", "TCGA-AB-2970", "TCGA-AB-2971", "TCGA-AB-2973", 
"TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2979", 
"TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2982", "TCGA-AB-2983", 
"TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2986", "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2988", 
"TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-2991", "TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2994", 
"TCGA-AB-2995", "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2999", 
"TCGA-AB-3000", "TCGA-AB-3001", "TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-3007", 
"TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-3011", "TCGA-AB-3012"
), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L
), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), FAB = structure(c(5L, 
1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4", 
"M5", "M6", "M7", "nc"), class = "factor"), `Diagnosis-Age` = c(63L, 
39L, 76L, 62L, 42L, 42L), `Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage` = c(82L, 
83L, 91L, 72L, 68L, 88L), Cytogenetics = structure(c(75L, 93L, 
51L, 27L, 21L, 57L), .Label = c("37~49,XY,+Y,der(1)add(1)(p13)del(1)(q21q25),-5,der(7)inv(7)(p15q11.2)?inv(7)(q22q32),+17,add(17)(p13),+21,+mar[cp20]", 
"39~47,XX,del(5)(q13q33),-7,der(8)t(8;?8;8)(p23;?p11.2p23;q11.2),der(14)t(1;14)(p12;p11.2)der(1)t(7;16)(p15;q22),+2mar[cp19]", 
"41~44,X,?i(X)(p10),-7,der(12)t(8;12)(q11.2;p11.2),-8 [cp11]/46,XX[8[", 
"42,XY,-5,-7,add(12)(p13),t(14;15)(q10;q10),der(17)t(5;17)(p13;p11.2),-18[6]/40,idem,-11,-add(12)(p13),der(12)t(?;12)(?;p13),-19[6]/41,idem,-der(17)[3]/41,idem,-der(17),+mar1,+mar[3]/41,idem,der(1)der(1)(p12)add(1)(p12),+der(1)(q21)add(1)(q21),-3,-8[2]", 
"43,XY-3,del(5)(q12q33),-7,der(10)t(10;11)(q26;q13),-12,-18,+2mar[20]", 
"44-45,X,-Y,-5,add(16)(q22),-17,-18,iso(21),+mars[cp5]/82-84,XX,-Y,-3,-4,-11,-12,-19,-21,+21[cp5}", 
"44~46,XX,del(11)(q23),der(19)?t(11;19)(q23;p13.1)[cp11]/44~45,XX,-19[cp4]/46,XX [5]", 
"44~47,XX,t(1;15)(q32;q26)[14],del(5)(q13q33)[19],-7[20],+8[7],del(12)(p11.2p11.2)[15],del(17)(q21)[8],der(22)t(1;22)(p13;p11.2)[20],+mar[13][cp20]", 
"44~47,XY,del(5)(q22q35)[20],-7[14],-8[6],der(12)t(10;12)(p11.2q21)[2],add(14)(p12)[11],-17[13],der(17)t(10;17)(q11.2;p13)[14],-18[7],add(18)(p11.2)[7],-21[10],i(21)(q10)[4],-22[4],+mar[10],+mar1x2[6][cp20]", 
"45,X,-X,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[20]", "45,X,-Y, t(8;7;21)(q22;p15;q22[22]/46,XY[3]", 
"45,X,-Y,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[13]/45,idem,del(9)(q22;q32)[7]", "45,X,-Y,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[19]/46,XY[1]", 
"45,X,-Y[3]/46,XY [17]", "45,XX-7[5]-only 5 metaphases", "45,XX,-7,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[19]/46,XX[1]", 
"45,XX,-7[12]/46,XX[8]", "45,XX,-7[20]", "45,XY,-7, t(9;22)(q34;q11.20) [19]/46,XY[1]", 
"45,XY,-7[20]", "45,XY,der(7)(t:7;12)(p11.1;p11.2),-12,-13,+mar[19]/46,XY[1]", 
"45~46,XY,add(X)(q22)[7],Y[4],der(5)t(5;17)(q13;21)[18],-7[18],+8[17],del(12)(q23)[16],-17[18],add(18)(p11.2)[14][cp18]", 
"46, XX[14]", "46, XX[15]", "46, XX[16]", "46, XX[19]", "46, XX[20]", 
"46, XY[15]", "46, XY[20]", "46,XX,1~50dmin[12]/46,idem,der(6)t(6;?)(q22;?)[2]/46,XX[6]", 
"46,XX,9qh+[20]", "46,XX,del(3)(q23q26.2),der(7)t(1:7)(q32;q32),del(10)(q22q25),t(13;16)(q34;p11.2)dup(21)(q22)[cp20]", 
"46,XX,del(5)(q11.2q33)[1]/48~52,idem,+1,+?del(5)(q15q33),+11,+11,?t(12;22)(p13;q12),-13,-17,+i(22)(q10),+i(22)(q10),+mar[cp19]", 
"46,XX,del(5)(q22q33)[4]/46,XX[16]", "46,XX,i(17)(q10)[1]/45,sl-7[2]/48,sl,+13,+19[3]/46,XX[15]", 
"46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[15]/46,XX[2]", "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[19]/46,XX[1]", 
"46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[20]", "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[5]/46,idem,t(3;3)(p13;q?28)[5]/46,XX[6]", 
"46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21.1)[19]/47,idem,+8 [1]", "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21),t(16;19)(p13.3;p13.1)[17]/46,XX[3]", 
"46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[11]/46,XX[9]", "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[12]/46,XX[8]", 
"46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[20]", "46,XX,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[17]/46,XX[3]", 
"46,XX,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[20]", "46,XX,t(8;21)[15]/46,idem,del(9)(q12q22)[5]", 
"46,XX[15]", "46,XX[18]", "46,XX[19]/46,XX,add(7)(p?22)[1]", 
"46,XX[20]", "46,XX+13,21[cp17]/46,XX[3]", "46,XY,9qh+[19]", 
"46,XY,del(11)(p12)[2]/46,XY[18]", "46,XY,del(20)(q11.2)[23]/92,XXYY,del(20)(q11.2)x2[2]/46,XY[3]", 
"46,XY,del(7)(q21q36)[18]/46,XY[2]", "46,XY,del(9)(q13:q22),t(11:21)(p13;q22),t(15;17)(q22;q210[20]", 
"46,XY,i(17)(q10)[15]/47,XY,idem+13[3]/46,XY[2]", "46,XY,inv(16)(p13;q22)[20]", 
"46,XY,inv(16)(p13q22)[17]/46,XY[3]", "46,XY,inv(16)(p13q22)[9]/46,XY[10]", 
"46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13)[17]/46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13),inv(12)(p12p13)[3]", 
"46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13)[20]", "46,XY,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[19]/46,XY[1]", 
"46,XY,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[20]", "46,XY,t(15;17)(q22:q21)[11]/46,XY[9]", 
"46,XY,t(2;4)(q34;q21)inv(16)(p13q22) [20]", "46,XY,t(6;11)(q27;q23)[15]", 
"46,XY,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[7]/47,XY,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[7]/46,XY[4]", 
"46,XY,t(9;22)(q34;q11.2)[13]/34~37,idem,-3,del(4),-4,-5,-7,-9,-10,t?(11;12),-12,-14,-14,-16,-17,-22[cp6]/46,XY[1]", 
"46,XY,t(9;22)(q34;q11.2[4]/50,idem,+8,+10,+21,+der(22)(t(9;22)(q34;q11.2)[16]", 
"46,XY[13]", "46,XY[15]", "46,XY[19]", "46,XY[20]", "46,XY[30]", 
"46~49,XY,del(3)(p14),del(5)(p11.2q33),del(17)(q21q21),add(21)(p11.2),+22,mar[cp20]", 
"47,XX,+der(5)t(2;5)(p11.2;q11.2)?,t(8;16)(p11.2;p13.3)[19]", 
"47,XX,i(11)(q10)[18]/46,XX [2]", "47,XX,t(15;17)(q22:q21)+mar[20]", 
"47,XX+11 [20]", "47,XX+8 [20]", "47,XXY [17]", "47,XY,+13[5]/46,XY[15]", 
"47,XY,+21 [6]/46,XY[13]", "47,XY,+21[11]/48,XY,+3,+21[8]", "47,XY,+22[10]/47,XY,+8[7]/45,XY,del(3)(p21),del(4)(p12p15),-7,?dup(7)(q11.2q36)[3]", 
"47,XY,+8 [10]/46,XY [10]", "47,XY,+8 [19]", "47,XY,+8 [20]", 
"47,XY,+8[15]/46,+8,-17[3]", "47,XY,+9[10]/46,XY[10]", "47,XY,del(5)(q22q33),t(10;11)(p13~p15;q22~23),i(17)(q10)[3]/46,XY[17]", 
"47,XY,del(7)(q22),+8,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[18]/46,XY,del(7)(q22),t(15;17)(q22;q21)[2]", 
"47,XY+8 [15]/48,XY+8+8[4]/46,XY[1]", "48,XY,+8,+8[16]/46,XY[4]", 
"52~54,XY,+2,+4,+6,+8,del(11)(q23),+19,+19,+21[17]/46,XY[3]", 
"53~56,XY,+1,del(2)(q33q34),+8,+10,+11x2,+13x1-2,+14,del(17)(p11.2),+19,add(21)(q22),+22[cp20]", 
"incomplete-46,XY,del(12)(p11.20[2]/46,XY[3]", "N.D.", "ND", 
"Outside hospital with inv(16)"), class = "factor"), `Cytogenetic-Code--Other-` = structure(c(8L, 
3L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 9L), .Label = c("BCR-ABL1", "CBFB-MYH11", "Complex Cytogenetics", 
"Intermediate Risk Cytogenetic Abnormality", "MLL translocation, poor risk", 
"MLL translocation, t(9;11)", "N.D.", "Normal Karyotype", "PML-RARA", 
"Poor Risk Cytogenetic Abnormality", "RUNX1-RUNX1T1"), class = "factor"), 
    Induction = structure(c(11L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 9L), .Label = c("7+3", 
    "7+3, dauna", "7+3, IT", "7+3+3", "7+3+3, gleevec", "7+3+3, then 5+2+2", 
    "7+3+3+PSC", "7+3+AMD", "7+3+ATRA", "7+3+dauno", "7+3+Genasense", 
    "7+3+study drug", "7+4+ATRA", "Azacitidine", "CLAM", "Cytarabine only", 
    "Decitabine", "Decitabine then 7+3", "Hydrea & Idarubicin", 
    "Hydrea, ATRA started", "hydrea, didn't get add'l chemo", 
    "LBH/Decitabine", "low dose Ara C", "no treatment", "Revlimid", 
    "Revlmd then Decitbne,7+3,5+2"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

**My attempt so far**

```
df <- plot_meta %>% group_by(patient) %>% count(Sex,FAB,`Diagnosis-Age`) %>% mutate(Percent = n / sum(n)*100)
head(df)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Sex, y = Percent, fill = FAB))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(Percent,"%"), y = Percent), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5))+
  coord_flip()+
  labs(x = "Sex", y = "Percentage",fill = "FAB")
```

The figure Im getting is this

How do I incorporate other variables distribution in the same plot as above? I would like to add the percentage scale on the axis such that a common percent scale for all the variables is there on one axis.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated

[image: this figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggnewscale)

plot_meta <- structure(list(
  patient = structure(c(
    36L, 33L, 122L, 95L, 66L,
    49L
  ), .Label = c(
    "TCGA-AB-2805", "TCGA-AB-2806", "TCGA-AB-2808",
    "TCGA-AB-2810", "TCGA-AB-2811", "TCGA-AB-2812", "TCGA-AB-2813",
    "TCGA-AB-2814", "TCGA-AB-2815", "TCGA-AB-2817", "TCGA-AB-2818",
    "TCGA-AB-2819", "TCGA-AB-2820", "TCGA-AB-2821", "TCGA-AB-2822",
    "TCGA-AB-2823", "TCGA-AB-2825", "TCGA-AB-2826", "TCGA-AB-2828",
    "TCGA-AB-2830", "TCGA-AB-2834", "TCGA-AB-2835", "TCGA-AB-2836",
    "TCGA-AB-2839", "TCGA-AB-2840", "TCGA-AB-2841", "TCGA-AB-2842",
    "TCGA-AB-2843", "TCGA-AB-2844", "TCGA-AB-2845", "TCGA-AB-2846",
    "TCGA-AB-2847", "TCGA-AB-2849", "TCGA-AB-2851", "TCGA-AB-2853",
    "TCGA-AB-2856", "TCGA-AB-2857", "TCGA-AB-2858", "TCGA-AB-2859",
    "TCGA-AB-2861", "TCGA-AB-2862", "TCGA-AB-2863", "TCGA-AB-2865",
    "TCGA-AB-2866", "TCGA-AB-2867", "TCGA-AB-2869", "TCGA-AB-2870",
    "TCGA-AB-2871", "TCGA-AB-2872", "TCGA-AB-2873", "TCGA-AB-2874",
    "TCGA-AB-2875", "TCGA-AB-2876", "TCGA-AB-2877", "TCGA-AB-2878",
    "TCGA-AB-2880", "TCGA-AB-2881", "TCGA-AB-2882", "TCGA-AB-2883",
    "TCGA-AB-2884", "TCGA-AB-2885", "TCGA-AB-2886", "TCGA-AB-2888",
    "TCGA-AB-2889", "TCGA-AB-2890", "TCGA-AB-2891", "TCGA-AB-2892",
    "TCGA-AB-2893", "TCGA-AB-2894", "TCGA-AB-2895", "TCGA-AB-2896",
    "TCGA-AB-2897", "TCGA-AB-2898", "TCGA-AB-2899", "TCGA-AB-2900",
    "TCGA-AB-2901", "TCGA-AB-2908", "TCGA-AB-2910", "TCGA-AB-2911",
    "TCGA-AB-2912", "TCGA-AB-2913", "TCGA-AB-2914", "TCGA-AB-2915",
    "TCGA-AB-2916", "TCGA-AB-2917", "TCGA-AB-2918", "TCGA-AB-2919",
    "TCGA-AB-2920", "TCGA-AB-2921", "TCGA-AB-2924", "TCGA-AB-2925",
    "TCGA-AB-2927", "TCGA-AB-2928", "TCGA-AB-2929", "TCGA-AB-2930",
    "TCGA-AB-2931", "TCGA-AB-2932", "TCGA-AB-2933", "TCGA-AB-2934",
    "TCGA-AB-2935", "TCGA-AB-2936", "TCGA-AB-2937", "TCGA-AB-2938",
    "TCGA-AB-2939", "TCGA-AB-2940", "TCGA-AB-2941", "TCGA-AB-2942",
    "TCGA-AB-2943", "TCGA-AB-2944", "TCGA-AB-2946", "TCGA-AB-2948",
    "TCGA-AB-2949", "TCGA-AB-2950", "TCGA-AB-2952", "TCGA-AB-2955",
    "TCGA-AB-2956", "TCGA-AB-2959", "TCGA-AB-2963", "TCGA-AB-2965",
    "TCGA-AB-2966", "TCGA-AB-2970", "TCGA-AB-2971", "TCGA-AB-2973",
    "TCGA-AB-2975", "TCGA-AB-2976", "TCGA-AB-2977", "TCGA-AB-2979",
    "TCGA-AB-2980", "TCGA-AB-2981", "TCGA-AB-2982", "TCGA-AB-2983",
    "TCGA-AB-2984", "TCGA-AB-2986", "TCGA-AB-2987", "TCGA-AB-2988",
    "TCGA-AB-2990", "TCGA-AB-2991", "TCGA-AB-2992", "TCGA-AB-2994",
    "TCGA-AB-2995", "TCGA-AB-2996", "TCGA-AB-2998", "TCGA-AB-2999",
    "TCGA-AB-3000", "TCGA-AB-3001", "TCGA-AB-3002", "TCGA-AB-3007",
    "TCGA-AB-3008", "TCGA-AB-3009", "TCGA-AB-3011", "TCGA-AB-3012"
  ), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), FAB = structure(c(
    5L,
    1L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L
  ), .Label = c(
    "M0", "M1", "M2", "M3", "M4",
    "M5", "M6", "M7", "nc"
  ), class = "factor"), `Diagnosis-Age` = c(
    63L,
    39L, 76L, 62L, 42L, 42L
  ), `Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage` = c(
    82L,
    83L, 91L, 72L, 68L, 88L
  ), Cytogenetics = structure(c(
    75L, 93L,
    51L, 27L, 21L, 57L
  ), .Label = c(
    "37~49,XY,+Y,der(1)add(1)(p13)del(1)(q21q25),-5,der(7)inv(7)(p15q11.2)?inv(7)(q22q32),+17,add(17)(p13),+21,+mar[cp20]",
    "39~47,XX,del(5)(q13q33),-7,der(8)t(8;?8;8)(p23;?p11.2p23;q11.2),der(14)t(1;14)(p12;p11.2)der(1)t(7;16)(p15;q22),+2mar[cp19]",
    "41~44,X,?i(X)(p10),-7,der(12)t(8;12)(q11.2;p11.2),-8 [cp11]/46,XX[8[",
    "42,XY,-5,-7,add(12)(p13),t(14;15)(q10;q10),der(17)t(5;17)(p13;p11.2),-18[6]/40,idem,-11,-add(12)(p13),der(12)t(?;12)(?;p13),-19[6]/41,idem,-der(17)[3]/41,idem,-der(17),+mar1,+mar[3]/41,idem,der(1)der(1)(p12)add(1)(p12),+der(1)(q21)add(1)(q21),-3,-8[2]",
    "43,XY-3,del(5)(q12q33),-7,der(10)t(10;11)(q26;q13),-12,-18,+2mar[20]",
    "44-45,X,-Y,-5,add(16)(q22),-17,-18,iso(21),+mars[cp5]/82-84,XX,-Y,-3,-4,-11,-12,-19,-21,+21[cp5}",
    "44~46,XX,del(11)(q23),der(19)?t(11;19)(q23;p13.1)[cp11]/44~45,XX,-19[cp4]/46,XX [5]",
    "44~47,XX,t(1;15)(q32;q26)[14],del(5)(q13q33)[19],-7[20],+8[7],del(12)(p11.2p11.2)[15],del(17)(q21)[8],der(22)t(1;22)(p13;p11.2)[20],+mar[13][cp20]",
    "44~47,XY,del(5)(q22q35)[20],-7[14],-8[6],der(12)t(10;12)(p11.2q21)[2],add(14)(p12)[11],-17[13],der(17)t(10;17)(q11.2;p13)[14],-18[7],add(18)(p11.2)[7],-21[10],i(21)(q10)[4],-22[4],+mar[10],+mar1x2[6][cp20]",
    "45,X,-X,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[20]", "45,X,-Y, t(8;7;21)(q22;p15;q22[22]/46,XY[3]",
    "45,X,-Y,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[13]/45,idem,del(9)(q22;q32)[7]", "45,X,-Y,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[19]/46,XY[1]",
    "45,X,-Y[3]/46,XY [17]", "45,XX-7[5]-only 5 metaphases", "45,XX,-7,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[19]/46,XX[1]",
    "45,XX,-7[12]/46,XX[8]", "45,XX,-7[20]", "45,XY,-7, t(9;22)(q34;q11.20) [19]/46,XY[1]",
    "45,XY,-7[20]", "45,XY,der(7)(t:7;12)(p11.1;p11.2),-12,-13,+mar[19]/46,XY[1]",
    "45~46,XY,add(X)(q22)[7],Y[4],der(5)t(5;17)(q13;21)[18],-7[18],+8[17],del(12)(q23)[16],-17[18],add(18)(p11.2)[14][cp18]",
    "46, XX[14]", "46, XX[15]", "46, XX[16]", "46, XX[19]", "46, XX[20]",
    "46, XY[15]", "46, XY[20]", "46,XX,1~50dmin[12]/46,idem,der(6)t(6;?)(q22;?)[2]/46,XX[6]",
    "46,XX,9qh+[20]", "46,XX,del(3)(q23q26.2),der(7)t(1:7)(q32;q32),del(10)(q22q25),t(13;16)(q34;p11.2)dup(21)(q22)[cp20]",
    "46,XX,del(5)(q11.2q33)[1]/48~52,idem,+1,+?del(5)(q15q33),+11,+11,?t(12;22)(p13;q12),-13,-17,+i(22)(q10),+i(22)(q10),+mar[cp19]",
    "46,XX,del(5)(q22q33)[4]/46,XX[16]", "46,XX,i(17)(q10)[1]/45,sl-7[2]/48,sl,+13,+19[3]/46,XX[15]",
    "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[15]/46,XX[2]", "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[19]/46,XX[1]",
    "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[20]", "46,XX,inv(16)(p13q22)[5]/46,idem,t(3;3)(p13;q?28)[5]/46,XX[6]",
    "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21.1)[19]/47,idem,+8 [1]", "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21),t(16;19)(p13.3;p13.1)[17]/46,XX[3]",
    "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[11]/46,XX[9]", "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[12]/46,XX[8]",
    "46,XX,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[20]", "46,XX,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[17]/46,XX[3]",
    "46,XX,t(8;21)(q22;q22)[20]", "46,XX,t(8;21)[15]/46,idem,del(9)(q12q22)[5]",
    "46,XX[15]", "46,XX[18]", "46,XX[19]/46,XX,add(7)(p?22)[1]",
    "46,XX[20]", "46,XX+13,21[cp17]/46,XX[3]", "46,XY,9qh+[19]",
    "46,XY,del(11)(p12)[2]/46,XY[18]", "46,XY,del(20)(q11.2)[23]/92,XXYY,del(20)(q11.2)x2[2]/46,XY[3]",
    "46,XY,del(7)(q21q36)[18]/46,XY[2]", "46,XY,del(9)(q13:q22),t(11:21)(p13;q22),t(15;17)(q22;q210[20]",
    "46,XY,i(17)(q10)[15]/47,XY,idem+13[3]/46,XY[2]", "46,XY,inv(16)(p13;q22)[20]",
    "46,XY,inv(16)(p13q22)[17]/46,XY[3]", "46,XY,inv(16)(p13q22)[9]/46,XY[10]",
    "46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13)[17]/46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13),inv(12)(p12p13)[3]",
    "46,XY,t(11;19)(q23;p13)[20]", "46,XY,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[19]/46,XY[1]",
    "46,XY,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[20]", "46,XY,t(15;17)(q22:q21)[11]/46,XY[9]",
    "46,XY,t(2;4)(q34;q21)inv(16)(p13q22) [20]", "46,XY,t(6;11)(q27;q23)[15]",
    "46,XY,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[7]/47,XY,t(9;11)(p22;q23)[7]/46,XY[4]",
    "46,XY,t(9;22)(q34;q11.2)[13]/34~37,idem,-3,del(4),-4,-5,-7,-9,-10,t?(11;12),-12,-14,-14,-16,-17,-22[cp6]/46,XY[1]",
    "46,XY,t(9;22)(q34;q11.2[4]/50,idem,+8,+10,+21,+der(22)(t(9;22)(q34;q11.2)[16]",
    "46,XY[13]", "46,XY[15]", "46,XY[19]", "46,XY[20]", "46,XY[30]",
    "46~49,XY,del(3)(p14),del(5)(p11.2q33),del(17)(q21q21),add(21)(p11.2),+22,mar[cp20]",
    "47,XX,+der(5)t(2;5)(p11.2;q11.2)?,t(8;16)(p11.2;p13.3)[19]",
    "47,XX,i(11)(q10)[18]/46,XX [2]", "47,XX,t(15;17)(q22:q21)+mar[20]",
    "47,XX+11 [20]", "47,XX+8 [20]", "47,XXY [17]", "47,XY,+13[5]/46,XY[15]",
    "47,XY,+21 [6]/46,XY[13]", "47,XY,+21[11]/48,XY,+3,+21[8]", "47,XY,+22[10]/47,XY,+8[7]/45,XY,del(3)(p21),del(4)(p12p15),-7,?dup(7)(q11.2q36)[3]",
    "47,XY,+8 [10]/46,XY [10]", "47,XY,+8 [19]", "47,XY,+8 [20]",
    "47,XY,+8[15]/46,+8,-17[3]", "47,XY,+9[10]/46,XY[10]", "47,XY,del(5)(q22q33),t(10;11)(p13~p15;q22~23),i(17)(q10)[3]/46,XY[17]",
    "47,XY,del(7)(q22),+8,t(15;17)(q22;q21)[18]/46,XY,del(7)(q22),t(15;17)(q22;q21)[2]",
    "47,XY+8 [15]/48,XY+8+8[4]/46,XY[1]", "48,XY,+8,+8[16]/46,XY[4]",
    "52~54,XY,+2,+4,+6,+8,del(11)(q23),+19,+19,+21[17]/46,XY[3]",
    "53~56,XY,+1,del(2)(q33q34),+8,+10,+11x2,+13x1-2,+14,del(17)(p11.2),+19,add(21)(q22),+22[cp20]",
    "incomplete-46,XY,del(12)(p11.20[2]/46,XY[3]", "N.D.", "ND",
    "Outside hospital with inv(16)"
  ), class = "factor"), `Cytogenetic-Code--Other-` = structure(c(
    8L,
    3L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 9L
  ), .Label = c(
    "BCR-ABL1", "CBFB-MYH11", "Complex Cytogenetics",
    "Intermediate Risk Cytogenetic Abnormality", "MLL translocation, poor risk",
    "MLL translocation, t(9;11)", "N.D.", "Normal Karyotype", "PML-RARA",
    "Poor Risk Cytogenetic Abnormality", "RUNX1-RUNX1T1"
  ), class = "factor"),
  Induction = structure(c(11L, 4L, 1L, 8L, 4L, 9L), .Label = c(
    "7+3",
    "7+3, dauna", "7+3, IT", "7+3+3", "7+3+3, gleevec", "7+3+3, then 5+2+2",
    "7+3+3+PSC", "7+3+AMD", "7+3+ATRA", "7+3+dauno", "7+3+Genasense",
    "7+3+study drug", "7+4+ATRA", "Azacitidine", "CLAM", "Cytarabine only",
    "Decitabine", "Decitabine then 7+3", "Hydrea & Idarubicin",
    "Hydrea, ATRA started", "hydrea, didn't get add'l chemo",
    "LBH/Decitabine", "low dose Ara C", "no treatment", "Revlimid",
    "Revlmd then Decitbne,7+3,5+2"
  ), class = "factor")
), row.names = c(
  NA,
  6L
), class = "data.frame")

df <-
  plot_meta %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), as.character)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>%
  count(name, value) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(perc = n / sum(n) * 100)
df
#> # A tibble: 38 × 4
#> # Groups:   name [8]
#>    name                         value                                    n  perc
#>    <chr>                        <chr>                                <int> <dbl>
#>  1 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 68                                       1  16.7
#>  2 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 72                                       1  16.7
#>  3 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 82                                       1  16.7
#>  4 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 83                                       1  16.7
#>  5 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 88                                       1  16.7
#>  6 Bone-Marrow-Blast-Percentage 91                                       1  16.7
#>  7 Cytogenetic-Code--Other-     Complex Cytogenetics                     2  33.3
#>  8 Cytogenetic-Code--Other-     Normal Karyotype                         3  50  
#>  9 Cytogenetic-Code--Other-     PML-RARA                                 1  16.7
#> 10 Cytogenetics                 45,XY,der(7)(t:7;12)(p11.1;p11.2),-…     1  16.7
#> # … with 28 more rows

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, perc)) +
  geom_col(data = ~ filter(.x, name == "FAB") %>% rename(FAB = value), mapping = aes(fill = FAB)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(data = ~ filter(.x, name == "Sex") %>% rename(Sex = value), mapping = aes(fill = Sex)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(data = ~ filter(.x, name == "Induction") %>% rename(Induction = value), mapping = aes(fill = Induction)) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: fantastic answer ..is it possible for the legends to have different groups as shown the first figure?

Comment: @PesKchan Yes, there is R package  `ggnewscale`, I revised my answer

Comment: yes i installed ...and thank you for the wonderful answer